# "his" usage in Victorian English

Tags: nineteenth-century-english

From Pride and Prejudice:

> “My dear Mr. Bennet,” replied his wife, “how can you be so tiresome! You must know that I am thinking of his marrying one of them.”

What is the function of "his" in this sentence, is it possessive or just a Victorian way of "him."

Comment: It's not just Victorian.

Comment: Possessive pronouns are often used with gerunds. It used to be the rule to do so.

Comment: _Pride and Prejudice_ was published before Queen Victoria was even born!